# Golang ioutil.ReadAll endless loop

Tags: go

I am new to Golang.

I'm trying to understand how to use ioutil.ReadAll (non HTTP response). According to the source code (and docs):

```
// ReadAll reads from r until an error or EOF and returns the data it read.
// A successful call returns err == nil, not err == EOF. Because ReadAll is
// defined to read from src until EOF, it does not treat an EOF from Read
// as an error to be reported.
func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error) {
    return readAll(r, bytes.MinRead)
}
```

I've implemented an io.Reader here in this example (also [here](https://play.golang.org/p/3qWNoKBW1ft) on Go Playground):

```
// go version go1.13.5 darwin/amd64

package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

// Thing contains a body
type Thing struct {
    Body []byte
}

// Read reads from body into p
func (t Thing) Read(dst []byte) (n int, err error) {
    // Note: bytes.Reader does return io.EOF
    // https://golang.org/src/bytes/reader.go?s=1154:1204#L30
    reader := bytes.NewReader(t.Body)
    return reader.Read(dst)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Testing bytes")

    thing := new(Thing)
    thing.Body = []byte("Hello World")

    fmt.Println("thing.Body:", string(thing.Body))

    // This works
    buf := make([]byte, len(thing.Body))
    n, err := thing.Read(buf)
    fmt.Println("Amount read:", n)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("buf:", string(buf))

    // ReadAll runs forever....why?
    buf2, err := ioutil.ReadAll(thing)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("buf2:", buf2)

}
```

Above, the Read implementation works fine. It simply calls bytes.NewReader() and reads from that. However, when using ioutil.ReadAll on the struct, it runs forever (times out), and I don't understand why. Originally I thought that maybe there wasn't an EOF in there, but the bytes reader [source code](https://golang.org/src/bytes/reader.go?s=1154:1204#L30) does return io.EOF here:

```
// Read implements the io.Reader interface.
func (r *Reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if r.i >= int64(len(r.s)) {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }
    r.prevRune = -1
    n = copy(b, r.s[r.i:])
    r.i += int64(n)
    return
}
```

I have seen other implementations of this on http response bodies where they explicitly have to close the body after reading it, but I don't see any method on a byte reader to close that.

Can someone help me understand what's going on in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thing.Read is written to read Thing.Body repeatedly and without end.  What is the intended functionality of Thing.Read?

Comment: Thing.Read reads Thing.Body into a dst []byte.
ioutil.ReadAll(thing) should return the contents of Thing.Body...

Comment: Every call to `Read` instantiates a new `bytes.Reader` which means each call starts reading it again from the beginning.

Comment: The Read implementation must return io.EOF at the end of the stream. If it is your goal to create a io.Reader on the bytes in Thing.Body, then follow the code in bytes.Reader.Read (you can ignore the prefRune thing).

Comment: @CeriseLimón thanks for the comment, but I still don't understand why the original implementation does not work. I did get it to work by doing this: `n = copy(dst, t.Body)
 return n, io.EOF`, but that should have been handled by bytes.NewReader's io.Reader implementation.

Comment: If `len(dst) < len(t.Body)`, then delegation to Read on a freshly created bytes.Reader will not return `io.EOF`.   The  implementation `n = copy(dst, t.Body) return n, io.EOF` does not read all of `t.Body` when `len(dst) < len(t.Body)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new `bytes.Reader` every time `Thing.Read()` is called. `ReadAll()` will just keep calling your `Thing.Read()` function each time getting the same 11 bytes.

From your comments I think you only want to create it once, for example, in a "constructor" whence you don't need to store `Body` as it is stored in the `Bytes.Reader`.

```
type Thing struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func NewThing(s string) (t Thing) {
    t.r = bytes.NewReader([]byte(s))
    return
}

func (t Thing) Read(dst []byte) (n int, err error) {
    return t.r.Read(dst)
}
```

But then `Thing` is just a wrapper of `io.Reader` that has no purpose.  You may as well use an `io.Reader' directly.

```
    buf2, err := ioutil.ReadAll(bytes.NewReader([]byte("Hello World")))
```